# SPSS Chi square less than 5 frequencies

Tags: spss, chi-squared

I need to compare frequencies of a sample versus frequencies of the population. So let's say we have fictive example where I have 50 males and 40 females and the population is 100 males and 102 females.

In general one can use the Chi Square test for proportions to test whether the sample is different from the population based on these frequencies. But let's say I don't have 100 males and 102 females, but 20 males and 4 females. I cannot use the chi square because every cell has to have at least 5 observations.

What to do? Google says user the fisher exact test. But can you use that for proportion like this? And if so, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets take your example in which your population contains 100 males and 102 females, and your sample contains 20 males and 4 females.  You now want to test for equality of proportions between the sample and the population. You can configure the table yourself:

```
            Male Female  Total
Population  100  102     202
Sample      20   4       24
Total       120  106     226
```

Contrary to what you state in your question it is the **expected** frequency that should be higher than 5 in every cell not the observed frequency. The expected frequency = (row total * column total) / overall total). For none of your cells you will find an expected frequency with less than 5. Even for the cell with the observed value of 4.

However, should you find yourself in the situation where your expected frequency is lower than 5, you could choose to apply the Yates correction.

Using the fisher exact test, as you state, is also a valid solution. In this instance you can calculate this by hand. See second [table + formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)

Also take a look at this [site](http://www.biostathandbook.com/small.html).

Good luck.